# What is the purpose of this cookie?

Tags: cookies, firefox, web

I have a site. My site does not have any cookies. It is developed with Drupal 8(CMS) and have few articles. Just for a curiosity I did check whether my website uses cookies or not. I did use Firefox to check.

The Firefox message box showed that, your site is using cookies as shown below. What this cookies is for? Do I have to add information about this cookie in my privacy policy.

[image: cookies]

Comment: Could you post the name of the cookie? The name alone should not be sensitive information.

Comment: @Anders Hi, It does not have any logical name, it is a long combination of alpha-numericals. Even content is also alpha-numbericals in above image. Hence I did hide that. Do you want me to post that one?

Comment: I have a website that does not have cookies. Here's a cookie from that website. No, you can't see it. Tell me what it's for. :-) You have to admit this is hard to answer.

Comment: Do you use any in-built Drupal functionality for logins? Any analytics scripts GA/Piwik? We probably will need to see at least the name to give a useful answer... and probably not even then... Is it alphanumeric or Base64 or alphanumeric-hex (only 0-9a-f)?

Comment: @Jedi That is my question...:) I did not set anything by myself, So why it is showing and surprisingly Chrome is not showing this cookie.

Comment: @Jedi, I have set nothing special for login, I am using whatever plain drupal8 CMS is providing, is there any area where should I chekc in drupal 8?

Comment: @Jedi Looks your guess is right. That cookie is shown only when I logged in as administrator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cookie may be a Drupal or PHP session cookie.  Drupal is as PHP application.  PHPSESSID is the default PHP session cookie name.  Drupal overrides this default with a name starting with SESS, followed by a hash.  The hash is a hexadecimal representation of an MD5 hash of the session name or the value of the cookie_domain setting in the settings.php file.  Since you blocked the name, I can't tell for sure whether taht is what you are seeing.  [This](http://redcrackle.com/blog/how-detect-which-module-creates-session-cookie) may help.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is a SESS, and I later found that, that cookie is only appearing when I am logged in as a administrator.

Comment: The set cookie header should return from the HTTP PUT that authenticates, regardless of the account name.